# bind key click to selected item from a tree with python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, key-bindings

I am working on a "treeview" list of patient, in which we can search for a patient and select one. I would like to right-click on the selected patient and open a new page with info about the patient:

```
try:
    import tkinter
    from tkinter import ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tkinter
    import ttk


class Mainpage:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tkinter.Frame(self.master)
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(1, weight=3)
        self.master.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(4, weight=1)

        self.searchfield = tkinter.Frame(self.master)
        self.searchfield.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4)

        self.search_var = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.search_var.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode: self.selected)
        self.entry = tkinter.Entry(self.searchfield, textvariable=self.search_var, width=45)
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=3)
        self.searchbtn = tkinter.Button(self.searchfield, text='Search', command=self.selected)
        self.searchbtn.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.treeFrame = tkinter.Listbox(self.searchfield, width=45, height=150)
        self.treeFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=3)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview( self.treeFrame, columns=('Status', 'Name', 'Date'))
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='Status')
        self.tree.heading('#1', text='Name')
        self.tree.heading('#2', text='Date')
        self.tree.heading('#3', text='Transact Code')
        self.tree.column('#0', stretch=tkinter.YES)
        self.tree.column('#1', stretch=tkinter.YES)
        self.tree.column('#2', stretch=tkinter.YES)
        self.tree.column('#3', stretch=tkinter.YES)
        self.tree.grid(row=0, columnspan=4, sticky='nsew')
        self.treeview = self.tree

        self.i = 1
        self.patient_list = [{"Name":"Harry Thuku", "Date":"07.09.2017"},
                             {"Name":"stella stl", "Date": "07.09.2017"},
                             {"Name":"geg be", "Date": "07.09.2017"},
                             {"Name":"Henry Reeta", "Date": "06.09.2017"},
                             {"Name":"Henry Reeta", "Date": "06.09.2017"}]

        for p in self.patient_list:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', text="ID_"+str(self.i), values=
            (p["Name"], p["Date"]), tags=p["Name"])
            self.i = self.i + 1

        self.search_item = self.entry.get()
        for p in self.patient_list:
            if p["Name"] == self.search_item:
                self.selected(self.search_item)

        self.frame.bind("<Button-3>", self.click)
        self.frame.grid_location(0, 0)


    def selected(self):
        search_for = self.search_var.get()
        iid_to_select = ()

        if search_for != '':
            all_tags = self.master.tk.call(str(self.tree), "tag", "names")
            tags_to_select = tuple(filter(lambda tag: search_for.lower() in tag.lower(), all_tags))
            for sorted_tag in tags_to_select:
                iid_to_select += self.tree.tag_has(sorted_tag)

        self.tree.selection_set(iid_to_select)

    def click(self, event):
        print("Clicked at: ", event.x, event.y)
        self.master.withdraw()
        self.toplevel = tkinter.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.toplevel.geometry("480x480")
        app = PatientPage(self.toplevel)


class PatientPage:
    #.....
    pass



root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Login")
root.geometry("480x480")
Mainpage(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I am having trouble binding the right click of the mouse with the opening of the new window, I did some coding, but am not 100% understanding it hence it is not working...

Any thoughts on the subject would be helpful and appreciated!

Comment: Try to do "binding" to `treeview` first (`self.tree.bind("<Button-3>", self.click)`). Right now there's only one `bind` to a frame, so it's unclear what you're expecting from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, bind the right click on the tree, not on the frame, i.e. replace `self.frame.bind("<Button-3>", self.click)` by `self.tree.bind("<Button-3>", self.click)`.

Then, you need to know on which item in the treeview the user has clicked. For that you can use `self.tree.identify_row(event.y)` which returns the id of the item at position `event.y`.

And, if you need to, you can retrieve the information on the patient stored in the treeview with `self.tree.item(<item>, 'values')`.

So `click` becomes:

```
def click(self, event):
    item = self.tree.identify_row(event.y)
    if item:  # right click on a patient
        self.master.withdraw()
        self.toplevel = tkinter.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.toplevel.geometry("480x480")
        info = self.tree.item(item, 'values')
        print(info)
        app = PatientPage(self.toplevel)
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw that I was binding incorrectly to the frame and when followed your advice, managed to resolve the issue and make it working! Moreover, the binding is much clearer to me now!